# The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When using the bind method in the calendar control I get the error:    The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context. How Can I do this correctly? I need a way of checking against null values. it is within a Gridview control

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" SelectedDate='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Bind("valid_date").ToString()) ? "0000-00-00 00:00:00.000": Bind("valid_date").ToString() %>' ></asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: What are you trying to bind? Is this in a `GridView` or some other similar databound control? Where is `valid_from_date` coming from?

Comment: @DaveZych its in a GridView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SelectedDate = '<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Eval("valid_date"))) ? DateTime.MinValue : Eval("valid_date") %>'
```

Comment: Some explanation would help a lot. Why can't we use 'bind'? Is it deprecated or what?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `Eval`:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
    SelectedDate='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("valid_date").ToString()) ? "0000-00-00 00:00:00.000": Eval("valid_date").ToString() %>'>
</asp:Calendar>
```